# Gathering specific image and hardware information about multiple computers

Tags: powershell, wmi

What I'm trying to do is gather specific information from a large number of assets at my company, 100+.

The text file is just a list of computer hostnames

```
desktop12345
desktop23456
etc.
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
$assets = Import-Csv 'c:\users\xxxxx\desktop\tex docs\assets.txt'

foreach ($asset in $assets) {
  Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem |
    Select-Object CSname, OSArchitecture, version, BuildNumber, OSType, InstallDate,
                  operatingsystemsku, ServicePackMajorVersion, encryptionlevel | FL
}
```

But even though I have a list it only returns information about my asset. I'm thinking I need to substitute `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Desktop -ComputerName` in the first section, but not 100% sure how I should format it.

Maybe something like this:

```
$assets = Import-Csv 'c:\users\xxxxx\desktop\tex docs\assets.txt'

foreach ($asset in $assets) {
  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName |
    Select-Object CSname, OSArchitecture, version, BuildNumber, OSType, InstallDate,
                  operatingsystemsku, ServicePackMajorVersion, encryptionlevel | FL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guess depending on the formatting of your text file, assuming that it's straight up list of computers. If it isn't just a list, please edit the question to show what the file looks like.

```
$assets = Get-Content 'c:\users\xxxxx\desktop\tex docs\assets.txt'

$output = foreach ($asset in $assets) {
     Get-WmiObject -class Win32_operatingSystem -ComputerName $asset | 
         Select-Object  CSname, OSArchitecture, version, BuildNumber, OSType, InstallDate, operatingsystemsku, ServicePackMajorVersion, encryptionlevel
}
$output | fl
```

Edit:

Simplified per Ansgar Wiechers's suggestion

```
$assets = Get-Content 'c:\users\xxxxx\desktop\tex docs\assets.txt' 
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_operatingSystem -ComputerName $assets | 
    Select-Object  CSname, OSArchitecture, version, BuildNumber, OSType, InstallDate, operatingsystemsku, ServicePackMajorVersion, encryptionlevel |
    fl
```

Comment: No go, 

Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:5 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -class Win32_operatingSystem -ComputerName $asset | Select-Object  ...

Comment: looks right without seeing the textfile. might need "$assett" or a split...

Comment: That new error message is that you can't connect to that computer over WMI. Possible causes are incorrect values from `$asset`, the computer isn't on, or it is firewalled. Try taking the first entry from your file and running the command manually. e.g. Does `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "desktop12345"` work?

Comment: It works when I put in the asset name instead of $asset or $assets.I picked 4 at random from my list and made sure they're all online...interesting. So it's not them being off, or firewall disabled....Could writing my list in notepad ++ be an issue?

Comment: Is the output of `$assets[0]` the first computer in your list?

Comment: So I'm special. I forgot about the header with import-csv. switched to get-content and it's mostly working now. odd thing is it's giving the results twice for each asset. I'm testing with a smaller list of 3 to start for faster results

Comment: If an answer worked for you, then it is best practice to accept it.

Comment: Instead of querying each computer individually you could pass the list of all computer names to `Get-WmiObject`: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $assets`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good suggestion, edited. I'm too often focused on fixing the immediate issue when something can be done more optimally.